# How to add new column to oracle editioning view

Tags: oracle, view

Oracle EBS R12.2.9

I have to add a new column to an editioning view of a custom table in oracle EBS R12.2.9.
Table was created like this...
From AMTO: create table amto.mci_jjtest1(a number)
From APPS: exec ad_zd_table.upgrade('AMTO', 'MCI_JJTEST1') -- This creates editioning view and also synonym under APPS

Now, new column B number with data type, needs to be added to the table, and the editioning view needs to be modified to add that column to the editioning view. Kindly let me know what commands and steps, I need to follow. I understand the traditional approach, where we would alter table to add column, and create or replace view to add the column to the SELECT, Not sure how to add column to table and editioning view the correct recommended way. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For table alterations - after running the DDL run below script to regenerate the editioning view for syncing any table changes.

exec AD_ZD_TABLE.PATCH('AMTO','MCI_JJTEST1')